# Gradle build stuck at compile Java

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to build a project, but the gradle build is stuck on compile java, I don't know how to fix it:

[image: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details]

Answer (score 0):

Gradle is actually very specific what has happened. There're compilation errors in project `gene-model-dom`.

```
Execution failed for task ':gene-model:gene-model-dom:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler output for details
```

To see the exact errors, run the build again with `--info` switch. For example (your mileage may vary):

> gradlew --info :gene-model:gene-model-dom:compileJava